# Pi 4B Won't boot without HDMI cable plugged to Monitor

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, pi-4, headless, sense-hat

I am a beginner with Pi. I got a Pi4 with 4GB ram and Rasbian Full Desktop installed, SenseHAT attached as well. I did the wpa_wifi config file and it works fine, will connect to WIFI with Monitor attached.

When I try to boot Pi4 **without** HDMI monitor plugged in, the RED power light and SenseHAT board is on but it won't boot. When I mean it won't boot, I mean the Pi can't connect to a network and I couldn't ssh into it via another PC on the same network.

If I boot first and then immediately plug HDMI in 1 second later, it still won't boot.

If I boot with monitor ALREADY plugged in, it works fine, WIFI will connect automatically, can ssh, even I unplug it later, it still stays good.

Also when my Pi successfully boots with monitor, the SenseHAT board will switch off blank which means it's booted.
When I boot without HDMI monitor, SenseHAT stays on colourful led lighting which means it didn't boot....

So my conclusion is that it won't boot without HDMI cable connected to a monitor.

Because I am trying to make headless ssh connection available when I am outside.

Anyone can help?

Comment: This is exactly the situation I am facing. Also Pi-Newbe, also 4B, newest Firmware, but no extension board whatsoever.

Comment: I set vnc resoultion and enable composit in raspi-config and the problem solved:
`raspi-config > Display Options > Composite > Enable composite`,
If you dont have monitor you can change this config in `/boot/config.txt`:
change `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d` to `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,composite`

Comment: The above comment solved my issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that the Pi has booted, but you have asked it to do the **impossible** i.e. boot to Desktop when there is no default Desktop (an examination of the boot logs would probably confirm this). See [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

You have 2 options:-

1. Boot to console.
2. Force HDMI

   Uncomment the below line in the file `/boot/config.txt`:

   ```
   # uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
   hdmi_force_hotplug=1
   ```

The latter probably requires a default resolution to be set in `raspi-config` (at least on the Pi4 - earlier models defaulted to VGA resolution).

If you are not planning to use VNC the first  is preferable - you can always start GUI manually with `startx` when required if a monitor is attached.

My Pi boot headless with or without monitor.

Answer (score 7):

This in fact is a known problem with the Sense-Hat. See https://github.com/astro-pi/python-sense-hat/issues/96 for detail.

Apparently, the Sense-Hat interferes with the resolution auto-detection if there is no monitor attached (works fine with monitor attached).

The work around is to manually specify a resolution (you do not have to force HDMI). You can do that with:

sudo raspi-config -> Advanced Options -> Resolution

Pick any of the DMT modes you like, just not default. If you attach a monitor from time to time, pick the DMT mode appropriate for your monitor. If you fly headless all the time, it matters not.

This issue has been open for a while and with is being specific to Sense-Hat and with a reasonable workaround, I doubt it will get fixed any time soon.

Comment: Setting the default resolution will help even with vanilla Pi 4B (no sense hat). Without the default resolution being set, Pi 4B will boot and you can SSH in -- but cannot VNC in.